# How to loop comma separated values in shell script

Tags: shell, ksh

I tried to loop comma separated values with space, but not able to get the exact value since it has space in the string.

I tried in different ways, but i not able to get desired results.
Can anyone help me on this

```
#!/bin/ksh

values="('A','sample text','Mark')"

for i in `echo $values | sed 's/[)(]//g' | sed 's/,/ /g'`
do
  echo $i
done
```

My expected output is:

```
A
sample text
Mark
```

Comment: Unless you are getting `values` from somewhere else, you should make it a regular array: `values=(A "sample text" Mark)`. If you *are* getting it from somewhere else, have them send an easier-to-parse format, like JSON.

Comment: Your values value is not a comma separated. It's a literal string that also contains " and ( and ' and )

Answer (score 2):

First, change `values` to an array. Then iterating over it is a simple matter.

```
values=(A "sample text" Mark)
for i in "${values[@]}"; do
  echo "$i"
done
```

Comment: how can I change to array ?

Comment: values=('A','sample text','Mark')  how i will convert this comma seperated values to array ?

Comment: lose the comma `,`. `values=('A' 'sample text' 'Mark')`

Comment: @Gowtham Your current value is a *string* that looks an array with commas. This answer uses the array assignment syntax (note the lack of quotes; `a=(...)` is a special kind of assignment.)

Comment: i cant able to loop with this single quote value values=('A' 'sample text' 'Mark'). how can i loop this ?

Comment: I tired, its not working.                                                                                   
values=('A' 'sample text' 'Mark')
for i in "${values[@]}"; do
  echo "$i"
done

Comment: @Gowtham Can you please be more specific? For example, instead of saying "its not working" you can say "I put it in a file `foo.sh` and ran `sh foo.sh` but it says `foo.sh: 1: foo.sh: Syntax error: "(" unexpected` instead of printing the values on separate lines"

Comment: @Gowtham Are you sure you are actually using `ksh` to run your script? Not all shells support arrays.

Answer (score 0):

This is the same as [*Chepner's answer*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54671247/6136214), only kludgier, ([variable substitution](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=99035&seqNum=3)), and more dangerous, (the `eval`...), the better to use the OP's exact `$values` assignment:

```
values="('A','sample text','Mark')"
eval values=${values//,/ }
for i in "${values[@]}"; do
  echo "$i"
done
```

It works in `ksh`, but really, if at all possible try to use *Chepner's* simpler and safer `$values` assignment.

Answer (score 0):

Simply trim the quotes

```
#!/bin/ksh

values="('A','sample text','Mark')"
echo $values |  tr  -d "()'\"" | tr ',' '\n'
```

output:

```
A
sample text
Mark
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the single quotes for splitting the string (and quote `"$values"`).
When your `sed` supports `\n` for replacement into a line, you can do without a loop:

```
echo "${values}" | sed "s/[)(]//g;s/','/\n/g;s/'//g"
# or
sed "s/[)(]//g;s/','/\n/g;s/'//g" <<< "${values}"
```

When the values in your string are without a comma and parentheses, you can use

```
grep -Eo "[^',()]*" <<< "${values}"
```

Better is looking for fields between 2 single quotes and remove those single quotes.

```
grep -Eo "'[^']*'" <<< "${values}" | tr -d "'"
```